# ls("package:datasets") in R

Tags: r

Well I can see that `ls("package:datasets")`prints the names of some data frames but don't understand the single colon and why is the expression in quotes? Can someone explain this expression? 
Thanks

Comment: https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-ints.html#Namespaces provides a little insight. Quotes? Because it needs to be a string; the single-colon thing here is much different than the double `::` and triple `:::` references for finding objects within a namespace; this single `:` appears to be a *convention* for finding a particular environment/namespace based on the *name* (string) of a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The search list is where R looks for objects.  `search()` will display it.

```
> search()
[1] ".GlobalEnv"        "package:stats"     "package:graphics" 
[4] "package:grDevices" "package:utils"     "package:datasets" 
[7] "package:methods"   "Autoloads"         "package:base"
```

You can list the objects in any of these using `ls` with an argument equal to one of the names shown above or you can use its number.  For example, either of these work with the search list shown above:

```
ls("package:datasets")
ls(6)
```

Every time you use `library(...)` it adds to the search list.  For example, note that MASS was added to the search list after we used `library(MASS)`.

```
> library(MASS)
> search()
 [1] ".GlobalEnv"        "package:MASS"      "package:stats"    
 [4] "package:graphics"  "package:grDevices" "package:utils"    
 [7] "package:datasets"  "package:methods"   "Autoloads"        
[10] "package:base"
```

`attach(...)` and `detach(...)` can attach and detach certain other objects to the search list as well.

You might want to check out this link as well:
http://blog.obeautifulcode.com/R/How-R-Searches-And-Finds-Stuff/